# How to deserialize a json which has a vector of a struct(sent using c++,recieved using c#,wpf)

Tags: c#, c++, json

My server which is written in c++ has a struct with ints and strings in it and sends the json where json["rooms"]= vector of struct.
Now how can i deserialize it in c#/wpf i am using newtonsoft nugget where if i want to deserialize something i have to give it's type and i cant seem to find out how to do that.
here is the struct in c++

```
{
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    std::string maxPlayers;
    unsigned int timePerQuestion;
    unsigned int isActive;
    unsigned int questionCount;
}typedef RoomData;
```

And this is the code that deserializes the packet
(I start at the index 6 because i have some bytes at the start that are a part of protocol
and are not needed by me in this stage)

```
private dynamic DeSerializePacket(byte[] response)
{
   Dictionary<string, dynamic> data = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
   string Jresponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
   data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,dynamic(Jresponse.Substring(6));
   return data;
}
```

This method basically uses the two methods to send and recieve the response from the server

```
private dynamic SendAndRecv()
{
   byte[] packet = SerializePacket();
   this.socket.Send(packet);
   byte[] response = new byte[4096];
   this.socket.Receive(response);
   dynamic SResponse = DeSerializePacket(response);
   return SResponse;
}
```

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> response = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
response= SendAndRecv();
???? rooms = response["rooms"];
```

Comment: where is the problem? Encoding.UTF8.GetString has overloaded (byte[] , int, int) so you can point start index you should use substring as UTF8 char not always takes 1 byte

Comment: When i try to take the vector out of the dictionary to use it it tells me its the wrong type

Comment: it tells you ... and you forgot tell us ... without [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is hard to help you

Comment: Is maxPlayers really supposed to be a string?

Comment: @GeirGrusom that is not the main problem right now although you are 100% right i'll change that later thank you

Comment: @Selvin i am super sorry for my bad explanation I think now after the edit it should explain it better

Comment: ???? => dynamic

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `std::vector<T>` in C# is `List<T>`. You're trying to read this as a hashmap of unspecified objects. You would at least need a list of these dictionaries though I generally advise against using dynamic unless there is a very compelling reason to use it.

As I understand it, you get an array of these RoomData structs and want to deserialize this into something similar to `std::vector<T>` but in C#.

I think this code should do the trick:

```cs
public sealed class Rooms
{
  public List<RoomData> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public sealed class RoomData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MaxPlayers { get; set; }
    public int TimePerQuestion { get; set; }
    public int IsActive { get; set; }
    public int QuestionCount { get; set; }
}

private List<Rooms> DeserializePacket(byte[] response)
{
    string jsonResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 6, response.Length - 6);
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rooms>(jsonResponse);
}
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure that json looks like `{ ... "rooms" : [ {RoomData1}, {RoomData2},  ...] ... }` so this will not work ... but OP is unable to write the question right

Comment: Then the solution is very simple: make a class that has a property called Rooms that is a `List<RoomData>`. This wasn't clear until the edit.

Comment: as Selvin said it was very close but it didnt work can you explain your solution in the comment a little more? @GeirGrusom

Comment: @GeirGrusom i get this Error when i try  (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "rooms" to type 'Trivia_GUI.RoomList'. Path '', line 1, position 7.')

Comment: I think an example of the request would be a lot more helpful than the C++ code to be honest.